# How do I detect a restricted PDF using command line?

Tags: pdf

Some PDF files have some flag set in them which disallows copying the content to clipboard. Printing and some other operations can be forbidden as well. The restriction usually can be easily removed with a `qpdf -decrypt` command.

What I want is to check if a PDF is restricted without applying the decryption operation (and without actually opening it and trying to copy something) so I can run a script to find all the restricted files under a specific file system.

Comment: Have you checked the output of the `file` command?  It may or may not include this info; I don't have restricted PDFs to be able to check.

Comment: @Wildcard, thanks for the idea but no, all it gives is "PDF document, version 1.7". As for having no restricted PDFs - you can hardly know for sure, some times it's a surprise. That's why I want to write a script to search through all the PDFs and check them.

Comment: @Ivan I notice one machine of mine will include that info: `PDF document, version 1.6 (password protected)`. It's using `file-5.39`. Another machine of mine is on `file-5.37` and doesn't show the "password protected" part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) provides a `pdfinfo` tool which can be used to determine the protections active in any given PDF. Restricted PDFs have encryption enabled, and `pdfinfo` will output (among other things) a line indicating this:

```
Encrypted:      yes (print:no copy:no change:no addNotes:no algorithm:RC4)
```

So something like

```
pdfinfo yourpdf.pdf | grep -q 'Encrypted:.*yes \(.*copy:no.*\)'
```

will only succeed if the PDF disallows copying.

Answer (score 4):

`qpdf` has also the ability to check for it. For instance you can use

```
qpdf --is-encrypted FILE.pdf
```

or

```
qpdf --requires-password FILE.pdf
```

The result can be accessed by `echo $?`. Check `qpdf --help=inspection` for further infos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pdfly`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfly/) which uses pypdf (I'm the author).

### Installation

It's a python package, so:

```
pip install pdfly
```

Depending on your system it might be `pip3`. Additionally, if it's only for your user, you might add the `--user` flag.

And you can use [`pipx`](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/) to install it.

### Usage

```
$ pdfly meta encrypted-pdf.pdf 
                     Operating System Data                     
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃         Attribute ┃ Value                                   ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│         File Name │ /home/moose/Downloads/encrypted-pdf.pdf │
│  File Permissions │ -rw-rw-r--                              │
│         File Size │ 18,950 bytes                            │
│     Creation Time │ 2023-07-02 23:23:18                     │
│ Modification Time │ 2023-07-02 23:23:18                     │
│       Access Time │ 2023-07-04 22:55:44                     │
└───────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┘
                 PDF Data                  
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃        Attribute ┃ Value                ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│            Title │                      │
│         Producer │                      │
│           Author │                      │
│            Pages │ unknown              │
│        Encrypted │ revision=6 v_value=5 │
│ PDF File Version │                      │
│                  │ endobj               │
│                  │                      │
│      Page Layout │                      │
│        Page Mode │                      │
│           PDF ID │ ID1=None ID2=None    │
│      Attachments │ unknown              │
│           Images │ 0 images (0 bytes)   │
└──────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
           Encryption information           
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┓
┃                        Attribute ┃ Value ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━┩
│ Security Handler Revision Number │ 6     │
│                          V value │ 5     │
└──────────────────────────────────┴───────┘
Use the 'pagemeta' subcommand to get details about a single page
```

Alternatively:

```
$ pdfly meta encrypted-pdf.pdf --output json
{"encryption": {"revision": 6, "v_value": 5}, "pdf_file_version": "\nendobj\n", "title": null, "producer": null, "author": null, "pages": null, "page_mode": null, "page_layout": null, "attachments": "unknown", "id1": null, "id2": null, "images": [], "file_permissions": "-rw-rw-r--", "file_size": 18950, "creation_time": "2023-07-02T23:23:18.056793", "modification_time": "2023-07-02T23:23:18.056793", "access_time": "2023-07-04T22:55:44.186378"}
```